# BrowserRouter.push is not a function error using React-Router-Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Following error is displayed while routing in case of 401 error using React-Router-Dom: -

**Code Snippet**

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      return response
}, function (error) {
   if (error.response.status === 401) {
        Router.push('/login');
        return Promise.reject(error);
   }
```

**Error Log: -**
react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.BrowserRouter.push is not a function

Any help/suggestions shall be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom history and use it. That will enable you to use navigate from outside of your components too

```
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

...
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>
...
```

and use it elsewhere too like

```
import { history } from './path/to/history';

...

    axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
          return response
    }, function (error) {
       if (error.response.status === 401) {
            history.push('/login');
            return Promise.reject(error);
       }
...
```